# proper tenses go with "in case"

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjunctions

> Eventually, this claim is still challenging and should be pursued by governments, in case , in near future, all cities' streets **would** lead to complete anarchy.

I am wondering if the tense of the verb that I have used, is grammatical.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think it might not be grammatical? Why have you chosen 'would lead'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are some other grammar problems in the rest of your sentence and it's not that easy to work out what you're trying to say, but I think it works better to actually drop the 'would'. It would really help to know the context a little more, but I would rewrite it like this:

> This claim remains a challenge and should be addressed by governments, in case all city streets lead to complete anarchy.